# How to start a swank server with slimv?

Tags: init

I installed slimv in my init file like this:

```
Plug 'kovisoft/slimv'
call Plug#end()
....

let g:slimv_swank_cmd = '~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/slimv/slime/start-swank.lisp'
```

But when i open a .lisp file, swank is not started. And when I  try to run Slimv.Repl.Connect-Server (or any command from the `,,` list) vim closes.

What am i doing wrong with setting up slimv?

Comment: Did you ran the `:PlugInstall` command?

Comment: Yeah, Slimv is already installed with :PlugInstall.

Comment: Do you have any error messages when you run `:messages`?

Comment: Yes - `indent blankline: Expected 4 arguements`

Answer (score 1):

I realize this answer is a bit late, but here is the solution for anyone else wondering.

As seen in the slimv tutorial, the `slimv_swank_cmd` should handle starting up a terminal window, an implementation of lisp that will be the server, and then load the `start-swank.lisp` file.

In your config, you've only specified the location of the file to load.

You should extend your command with a terminal and a lisp implementation, for example `xterm` and `sbcl`, as seen in the slimv tutorial:

```
let g:slimv_swank_cmd = '! xterm -e sbcl --load ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/slimv/slime/start-swank.lisp &'
```

Note that when you don't specify a `slimv_swank_cmd`, the lib should handle this setup for you automatically, in most cases.

If this didn't happen in your case, maybe the terminal or the lisp expected by the lib was not found on your system, and in the command you should specify the actual executables that are known to work for you.

See: https://kovisoft.github.io/slimv-tutorial/tutorial.html#configuration